# jQuery animations: fadeIn() hidden div, not showing content

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a button with the id of "start_game" that has an attached click function and a callback to fade the button out, and then fade in a div that is currently set by css to display:none.

When I click the button, I see that the outer container div that holds all of this expands as if to make room for the div that is to be displayed, however I never see the content that I have inside of it.

Here is the current code:

```
$("#start_game").click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $(".input-append").fadeIn();
    });
```

and the html

```
<div class="hero-unit">
        <div id="container">
            <p>Shall we?</p>
            <button class="btn-primary btn-large" id="start_game">Play!</button>
            <div class="input-append hidden">
                <p>How many players?</p>
                <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" />
                <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the only custom css, the other css file is twitter bootstrap

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

Now I have tried numerous approaches. I have tried fadeIn, I've tried chaining together a few different combinations of show() or hide() or toggle() or fadeToggle(). I have also tried attaching to the callback an iteration of all the child elements of the hidden div and doing fadeIn() one by one on them, nothing seems to be working.

I am testing in Google Chrome 26 and IE10.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that the CSS is set set display: none and not visibility: hidden? If it's set to visibility: hidden, this won't work

Comment: Can you post your CSS? I made a bare-bones copy and it appears to be working as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/wXdN5/

Comment: Is the `hidden` a class?  If so, you may have to trigger removing the class.  I have experience conflicts where the class's way of hiding an element  (e.g. Opacity:0, display:none) can override a jquery.show or jquery.fade method.

Comment: yes. the hidden is just a little utility class within the css that simply does display: none that is the only rule inside

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just ran into the same scenario. If I mark a twitter bootstrap control group hidden initially and then use `show()` method the outer div of the control group it is indeed shown but the contents of that control group div are still hidden.

The reason for that is bootstrap CSS looks for `.hidden` class to add visibility CSS rules to the inner divs as well, but the JQuery show() method does not remove the hidden class. It manipulates the CSS directly leaving the hidden class in place.

You can use `removeClass('hidden')` to remedy that problem.

Now the bonus question: how do we *animate* that transition??

And the answer is: `fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');`  Not very intuitive but hey, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#start_game").click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $(".input-append").fadeIn("slow").removeClass('hidden');
});
```