# jquery fadein() not working with hide() and display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems to be so easy to do. But, I can't make it work....! So frustrated...

I googled this problem and tried to solve it for a few hours. (I read a number of posts on StackOverflow.) But, I still can't solve this problem...

The following posts cover similar issues. So, I tried to solve my problem by trying answers in the posts. But, nothing worked for me...

- After reading this([jquery fadeIn not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398882/jquery-fadein-not-working)), I tried `.hide()`.
  : didn't work...
- After reading this([jQuery animations: fadeIn() hidden div, not showing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006100)), I tried `fadeIn().removeId('tutorialPages')`
  : didn't work...
- Also, I tried `display:none` in `CSS` instead of `.hide()` in `JS`.
  : didn't work...

**Please keep in mind:**
If you think it's a duplicate of another question, please let me know which one and how I can apply solution(s) in that question to my problem. I am new to JavaScript and it is still difficult for me to apply solutions that worked for same/similar issues to my problem. Thanks in advance! :-)

I am using `Bootstrap 4.1.2.` & `jQuery 3.3.1`.
(* you can't see the part I used Bootstrap in the following code snippet.)

**Error Message**:
I didn't see this error message when I wrote this code in `JSFiddle`. But, in this code snippet, the following code shows up when `Press this!` is clicked: `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadein is not a function"`.

**What I'm trying to do:**
1. When the page loads up, only `Press this!` is shown.
2. Show the 1st sentence when clicking `Press this!`.
3. Show the 2nd sentence when clicking the 1st sentence.
 
4. Show the 3rd sentence when clicking the 2nd sentence.
 
5. Show the 4th sentence when clicking the 3rd sentence.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#tutorialPages").hide();

  $('#test').click(function(){
    $("#tutorialFirst").fadein();
  });
  
  $('#tutorialFirst').click(function(){
    $("#tutorialSecond").fadein();
  });
  
  $('#tutorialSecond').click(function(){
    $("#tutorialThird").fadein();
  });
  
  $('#tutorialThird').click(function(){
    $("#tutorialFourth").fadein();
  });
  
});
```

```css
/* #tutorialPages{
  display: none; 
}  
 */
#tutorialGreen{
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 : jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
  <p id="test">Press this!</p>


<div id="tutorialPages">
  <p id="tutorialFirst">This is 1st sentence.</p>
  <p id="tutorialSecond">This is 2nd sentence.</p>
  <p id="tutorialThird">This is 3rd sentence.</p>
  <p id="tutorialFourth">This is 4th sentence.</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Hide the parent element - `$("#tutorialPages")`, so it doesn't matter what will happen to its child elements, they won't be shown.

`$("#tutorialPages")` should always be shown, and show/hide only the children elements, or add `$("#tutorialPages").show()` to the first click event.

Comment: ahhh!!! thanks!!! I didn't use `$("#tutorialPages").show()` and added `.hide()` for each sentence. It works as I intended! https://jsfiddle.net/hlim188/6x3nha87/50/

Answer (score 1):

It should be `.fadeIn()` with a capital I

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, I can accept only one answer and @Programmer's solution solved my main issue. So, I couldn't accept your answer. But, I voted up your answer. :)